# Why does my code return 2 when I think it should return 1? (Part of a Hacker Rank problem)

Tags: java

The output I believe should be 1, however I keep getting 2. The hacker rank problem is called "Migrating Birds". Essentially I am given an array of numbers that all must be the integers 1 - 5. All I have to do is determine which one shows up the most in the array. If a tie exists return the smallest integer that appears the most. Well my solution works great until their is a tie. For some reason perhaps basic and I am just missing it; my code updates 1 too 2 when I do not think it should. I am testing against my own input which is : 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5. Anyways if anyone would like to help me out it would be appreciated.

```
static int migratoryBirds(List<Integer> arr) {
        Map <Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int max = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
            if(map.containsKey(arr.get(i))){
                map.put(arr.get(i), map.get(arr.get(i)) + 1);
            }else{
                map.put(arr.get(i), 1);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getValue() > max){
                max = entry.getKey();
                System.out.println(max);
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
```

The input 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 gives 2, when I believe that my code should give 1.

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why, then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: I mean you are absolutely right about need to start debugging. I have been. I know that my program does set max to 1, but then on the next iteration through the map entries it sets max too 2; after that the program does not set max again. I have no idea why it does this because the value of key 1 is 2 and the value of key 2 is 2. So why would my program update max to be 2 when the value of key 2 is not greater than the value of key 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely in your `max` variable. You're comparing map values to `max` and then if the value is bigger than `max` you store a key of that value in `max`. In the next iteration you will be comparing a value to a key stored in `max`, that can't be right.

Hint: try maintaining two variables `maxKey` and `maxValue`. After you see it's working, clean the code of redundancy.